# slice (unsorted) array at value in python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

Given the array `a = [1,1,12,3,5,8,13,21]` I can slice off the first 3 elements like `a[:3]`  giving `[1,1,2]`. What I want is to slice off up to the element of vlaue `i` (e.g. if `i=8` I want `[1,1,12,3,5,8]` or `[1,1,12,3,5]` (I can work with either)).

This works:

```
return a[:a.index(i)]
```

but only if I give it a value that's in the array.

*Is there a clean built in way to do this that does something sane on the missing value case?*

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "something sane".

Comment: if a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21], do you want [1,1,2,3,5,8] or [1,1,2,3,5,8,4] ?

Comment: @Mark Byers: The whole array, a blank array or just about anything else that doesn't produce a 'WTF?!'

Comment: Would the down-voters care to comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. That's a `list`.
2. Try

   ```
   >>> a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
   >>> import itertools
   >>> for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda val: val != 8, a):
   ...     print x
   ...
   1
   1
   2
   3
   5
   ```

Comment: +1 for takewhile though I would say `val != 6` is more appropriate for an unsorted list.

Comment: `val != 6` returns the entire list when `6` is missing.

Comment: @Chris: that's ok. As would be returning  `[]`. But using `<`, `>`, etc. would be wrong as then it would stop on a 20.

Comment: @BCS: In other words, you don't care _what_ you get back, you just want to avoid an exception.  So why don't you just _catch_ the exception?

Comment: @Chris, I need a value so using a catch would make the code 5 times as long and would be no more readable (at best) than checking for that case with an if.

Comment: Five times as long?  `try: return a[:a.index(i)]; except: return []`

Comment: Returning meaningless values rather than raising exceptions when under exceptional circumstances sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @Chris: Is that a statement or an expression? Given that it will be replacing an expression (see Mike's answer) that doubles the size. Also I can take a million line C program and remove most of the \n's. That doesn't make it a l line program.

Comment: @Mike, In general, you are correct. In my case the choice is more or less arbitrary and either option is reasonable.

Comment: Number of lines is not typically a good thing to optimise for.

Comment: @Mike, "All else being equal"... Unless you/I can point at something (anything) that makes it *worse*, I'll generally prefer shorter code as it tends to more closely match what I want to say.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is sorted, use a binary search. The function is in the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html).

```
from bisect import bisect_right
a[:bisect_right(a, value)]
```

Comment: It was misleading to use a sorted example in the question, then.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generator, and use that:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]

def _gen(listing, cutoff):
    for i in listing:
        if i == cutoff:
            return

        yield i

new_a = list(_gen(a, 5))
```

... or, if you really want a slice ...

```
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if val == cutoff:
        break

new_a = a[:i]
```